# Unable to Get UIButton to Fade In on ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uibutton

As stated in the title, I am unable to get the UIButton to fade in on the ViewDidLoad method. Here is my code thus far:

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.nextButton.fadeIn(duration: 10.0, delay: 10.0)
    }
}
```

**UIViewExtensions.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func fadeIn(duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0, delay: NSTimeInterval = 0.0, completion: ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: completion)  }

    func fadeOut(duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0, delay: NSTimeInterval = 0.0, completion: (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Comment: You called fade in but are you sure you set the alpha to 0 previously. If you just initialized the view, you can't animate from 1 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to start any animations like a fade in, on the viewDidLoad. This method is called when the class is finished initializing (right after the init). It happens before the view is visible. You want to start animations in the viewDidAppear. This is called once the view is visible on the screen. When you start it in the viewDidLoad, it's already done the animation by the time it gets to the viewDidAppear, assuming of course you did the fade in over about .5 second.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that! I added it to the ViewDidAppear, however, the animation of the UIButton fading in still just simply appears.

Comment: yes it's a combination of both moving it to the viewDidAppear and setting the alpha to start with 0 before the animation block. Then you bring the alpha up to 1 over the duration inside the animation block.

Answer (score 1):

Set you button alpha to 0 on storyboard,so that you can fade in.

Because,if your button alpha is 1,then you want to animate to 1,IOS do nothing

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.button.fadeIn(duration: 3, delay: 0)

    }
```

Comment: AGH, I don't know how I could have forgotten this! Regardless, after setting it's alpha to 0, it still does not fade in – it instead remains invisible.

Comment: In your function,you have to wait 10 seconds. Set it to 0,and put it into viewDidAppear,See the updates .I think it is better,because your animate duration is too long